# How to import local model into Magenta MusicRNN?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, magenta

I have trained my model locally using the python libraries and got the 3 files:

- ckpt.index
- ckpt.meta
- ckpt.data

After that, I have followed the steps on this [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta-js/tree/master/music#model-checkpoints), under "Dumping Your Weights" and now I also have:

- [weights_manifest.json](https://jsonblob.com/e08b9301-383b-11e9-8243-11227c893fd6)
- group1-shard1of2
- group1-shard2of2

I have also this [config.json](https://jsonblob.com/0e014bfb-383c-11e9-8243-0d8da32e0e3d) file

But when I try to import it using the js library it crashes.

error log

[image]

values right before it crashes

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue apparently originated from the config file. As soon as I replaced the file with the one used in the default model ([config.json](https://jsonblob.com/92952827-38dc-11e9-a7e9-5df0d853eb88)), it worked.